# Showing that a non-standard basis for Polynomials is a basis

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $B_1 = \{ 1 + x, 1 - x \}$ be a subset of $P_1$ and $B_2 = \{ 1 + 2x, 2 + x\}$ be a subset of $P_1$. Both $B_1$ and $B_2$ are bases for $P_1$ , where the usual left to right ordering is assumed.

Show that $B_2$ is a basis for $P_1$.

I don't understand what $P_1$ is. Is it the set of polynomials of degree $1$? I've tried to set up several coefficient matrices for both of these, since $B_2$ and $B_1$ must be linearly independent if they are indeed bases but I have no idea how to set up such a matrix.

Comment: If $B_2$ is supposed to be a basis for $P_1$, then $P_1$ must be polynomials of degree at most $1$ (it will also include constant polynomials), but this is not completely standard notation, and whoever set this problem should have been clear about what they meant. For example, they should tell you which field the polynomials have coefficients in.

Comment: I'm just going to assume that that's what P[sub]1[sub] is. I still have no idea how to set up the coefficient matrix though.

Comment: To do that, you need to have a set that you *know* is a basis for $P_1$; then you can write the elements of these two candidate bases as linear combinations of elements in your basis, giving you the coefficient matrix.

Comment: Oh dear it seems like I missed part of the question when typing this. These two subsets are both known bases for P1. I'll edit the question

Comment: There's no need to set up a coefficient matrix to show $B_2$ is a basis for $P_1$. You just need to show that $B_2$ is a linearly independent set, and that it spans $P_1$, and you can do those by going back to the definitions. There are some shortcuts possible if you know a few facts about the concept of dimension.

Comment: So since 1 + 2x and 2 + x are not scalar multiples of each other, they are linearly independent. But since this is a polynomial of degree 1, it has at most 1 distinct root. Does this imply that P1 has dimension 1?

Comment: @AlexGun: No, if $P_1$ are the polynomials of degree at most $1$, then its dimension is $2$ (its "standard" basis is $\{1,x\}$.